# How to to extract a string between two characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

These are my strings:

```
there_is_a_string_here_1_480@1111111
there_is_a_string_here_1_360@1111111
there_is_a_string_here_1_180@1111111
```

What I want to do is extracting 180, 360 and 480 from those strings.

I tried this RegEx `_(.*)@` but no chance.

Comment: Maybe this: `_(\d*)@` - is it always a number string?

Comment: Yes it is. But this one includes _ and @ characters too. If you can also get rid off them too why don't you post an answer? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want the capture group:

```js
var str = 'there_is_a_string_here_1_180@1111111';
var substr = str.match(/_(\d*)@/);
if (substr) {
  substr = substr[1];
  console.log(substr);
}

//outputs 180
```

Comment: It will also throw a `TypeError` if there is no match (Cannot read property 1 of `null`).

Comment: See edit - if there is doubt that the string will conain the substr, just check for the match first, then select the capture group.

Answer (score 1):

you almost got it

```
_(\d{3})@
```

you need to do a match on digits, or else the string will also get selected because of the other underscore.

Ofcourse your match will be in `\1`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
    var str = "there_is_a_string_here_1_480@1111111";
    var matches = str.match(/_\d+@/).map(function(value){return value.substring(1,value.length-1);});
document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(matches,0,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

(?<=*(?!.**))(.*)(?=@)

Use lookbehind (?<=) and look ahead (?=) so that "_" and "@" are not included in the match.

*(?!.**) gets the last occurence of "_".

(.*) matches everything between the last occurence of "_" and "@".

I hope it helps.